# nRF52 GPIO configuration in sleep mode to prevent peripherals from drawing current

Tags: low-power, gpio, power-consumption, sleep, nrf52832

I have a battery-powered board with an nRF52832 and some peripherals that I am writing a new firmware for. When set to sleep (NRF_POWER->SYSTEMOFF=1;) the board still draws way too much current (around 2mA, the nRF is rated for <1 uA when in sleep). The pcb itself is fine, with the firmware it came with, the power consumption in sleep mode was very low. At first I thought this might be a software or configuration issue, but I guess it is probably the peripherals drawing too much power.

When the board is set to sleep mode, most of the SoC-internal peripherals are turned off, but the GPIO configuration is preserved. I tested the power consumption with minimal code (first statement in main() is sleep) so all GPIOs were set to default confguration (input with disconnected internal switch).

**Do I need to set the GPIOs to a certain configuration to prevent them from wasting power?**

- Some peripherals are connected via SPI or I2C. Should the nRF Pins
  used for SPI/I2C be in a specific configuration when SPI/I2C are not
  used, or is the default (input with disconnected internal switch)
  fine?
- One GPIO is driving a n-channel mosfet (with ext. pulldown on gate)
  that drives a small motor. I guess since there is an external
  pulldown, the default pin config should be fine?
- Some LEDs are connected (GPIO -> Resistor -> LED -> GND). Again, I guess default should be fine?
- Battery voltage is measured via ADC on voltage divider.
- A active-low switch has an external pull-up.

Is it for any of these peripherals critical to configure the GPIOs in a specific way to prevent power loss?

Schematics: https://mbientlab.com/community/uploads/editor/f6/3zbfr2s08vsb.pdf

(I was posting this question on the nordic forums, but I noticed that the issue is probably more general about GPIO configuration. [Link to Topic](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/61375/high-current-consumption-2ma-in-systemon-and-systemoff-sleep-sdk16-no-softdevice-with-some-other-peripherals))

**Edit:** I measured the current with a scope. I could not get to the voltage regulator pin (tiny) but I measured in series with the battery (put a 10 Ohm resistor in series with battery and measured with probes across the resistor). 10mV equals 1mA, so the scope shows around 2.2mA [image]

Comment: Few thoughts, I guess you're doing power cycling before measuring the current, so that the debug section of the chip powers off. One possibility is that the nRF is constantly resetting, can you check the 3V regulator output? Also why is the SWCLK pulled down?

Comment: Yes I disconnected the debugger and reconnected power before measuring the current. I assume that SWCLK is pulled down because the predecessor mcu (nRF51) hat a noise problem on the debug port which could be fixed with such a pulldown: https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/16435/is-external-pull-down-needed-on-swclk-for-nrf52. I will take some measurements on the 3V regulator with an oscilloscope.

Comment: @EarthLord I measured the current with a scope, I added a screenshot to my first post. Looks like the current drain is pretty much constant.

Comment: Make sure no I/O's are exerted against pulling resistors (including *internal* ones).  Make sure no I/O's are applying a logic voltage to any external peripheral chips when the supply to those chips has been turned off.   And realize that your voltage divider is going to consume power.   Commit your software in git and start taking out functionality, ie, never initialize this or that and see how the power changes.  Also consider running your software on a dev board or breadboard module with none of the external circuitry...

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this was pretty simple:

There are no external pullups on the CS lines of the SPI-connected ICs, so they were floating. Setting them to output high solved the problem.